# Create sum of sine wave series as matrix

Tags: matlab, sum, series

I want to create a function that represents a sum of sine waves of different frequencies modulated by n (which should run from 2 to 10, with interval of 1)

This function is then a function of time which will be a linear space from 0 to 3 second. And I need the result to be presented in a matrix. I have the problems with matrix dimensions and i dont know how to fix this.

```
t1 = linspace (0,3,1000);
n = 2:1:10;
S1 = sin(1/4 - 1/n.^2)*2*pi.*t1*440
```

Comment: Your expected result is not clear to me but you may be expecting `S1=sin(1/4-1./n.^2).'*2*pi.*t1*440` (with implicit expansion)

Comment: it fixes the problem! do you know how can I make the matrix from 9 rows to 1 row (by this i mean, the value of n is not differentiated)

Comment: If your expected result is for only one value of  `n` then why are you calculating `S1` for 9 values in the first place? If all you want is  to get all the values in a single row, read the doc  of `reshape`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you wanna do is something like:

```
S1 = sin(1/4 - 1./n.^2)*2*pi.*t1'*440
```

The vector n is sized (1x9) and t1 is sized (1,1000), so you just have to transposed the vector t1 with the symbol ' to respect the Algebra multiplication of matrices/vectors.

Hope it helped!